# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop in JDK 1.7

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, gmail-api

I am trying to use the Gmail API and I encountered this run-time exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop
```

It occurs here (on the last line):

```
    InputStream stream = ReadMail.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(ReadMail.JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    ReadMail.HTTP_TRANSPORT, ReadMail.JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, ReadMail.SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(ReadMail.DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();


    AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp authCodeInstalledApp = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver());
    Credential credential = authCodeInstalledApp.authorize("user");
```

This code is sitting in the `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`.

I have checked and Android Studio is configured to use JDK 1.7.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: This has to be a classpath issue, you are not including at runtime, some source that you had available at compile time.

Comment: @MattClark He's on Android.

Comment: You have to include the stack trace, not just the single line. We need to know which class load is triggering the problem.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that tag, but still, would that not be the problem alltogether? Are _java.awt_ packages even available on Android?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850911/java-awt-desktop-class This resolved me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not support all JDK classes, only a [subset](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) and `java.awt` is not part of it. Therefore `java.awt.Desktop` cannot be found. It seems like you're not using the right API at all. You should use [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering quick,  I've seen the Android Quickstart page but i can't use it since Im developing it for Android API 21. And the Android Quickstart only supported at  API 23

Comment: I have searched hours for some Gmail API code that works and what I found is this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java 
Didn't think that some java code can not work in Android. Do you have any solution for how to use Gmail API for Android 21 and not 23?

Comment: @TalMantelmakher It states *Android SDK packages for API 23 or later*. This doesn't mean only API levels 23 and later are supported.

Comment: But whenever i tried updating those SDK packages i got errors I could only fix by reverting those SDK packages to the older versions. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Without knowing any of your errors I would still say that you did something wrong. Question would be what. Try it again and ask new questions for the errors you cannot fix.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but just in case - Is it possible to include the Java.awt package in android somehow, to make the code i have work?

Comment: It might be possible but also not advisable. It's a package related to Desktop UI. You'd be fixing more issues with this than you'd have doing it correctly.

Comment: have anyone found a fix?