# AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp - Android Alternative

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to Authenticate into Google Oauth with Android, I successfully authenticate, store my credentials and auth token but then there's one particular piece of code that I am falling over at; returning an instance of `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp`. The problem seems to be that this API is made for Java desktop applications and is trying to load a browser instance. Here is my `GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule`, a slightly refactored version of the code that is shown in the Android developer docs:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import com.example.bluelightlite.constants.CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH
import com.example.bluelightlite.constants.JSON_FACTORY
import com.example.bluelightlite.constants.SCOPES
import com.example.bluelightlite.constants.TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader


class GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule constructor(private val context: Context): AsyncTask<NetHttpTransport, Void, Credential>() {

    /**
     * Starts getting credentials on a different thread by implementing
     * AsyncTask<>()
     * @param params: a list of parameters
     * @return Google Credentials that come from this.getCredentials()
     */
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: NetHttpTransport): Credential {
        return this.getCredentials(params[0])
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws java.io.IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private fun getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT: NetHttpTransport): Credential {

        val inputStream: InputStream = getCredentialsAsInputStream()
        val clientSecrets: GoogleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, InputStreamReader(inputStream))

        createTokenFolderIfMissing()

        val authorisationFlow: GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow = getAuthorisationFlow(HTTP_TRANSPORT, clientSecrets)
        val receiver: LocalServerReceiver = LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
            .setPort(8888)
            .build()

        return AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(authorisationFlow, receiver).authorize("user") //falls over here
    }

    /**
     * Gets the /credentials.json file
     * @return InputStream
     */
    private fun getCredentialsAsInputStream(): InputStream {
        return this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
            ?: throw FileNotFoundException("Resource Not found: $CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH")
    }

    /**
     * Creates the Tokens Folder for Google Authentication
     * Uses the current context for the folder path from
     * Context.getExternalFilesDir()
     */
    private fun createTokenFolderIfMissing() {
        val tokenFolder = getTokenFolder()
        if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
            tokenFolder.mkdir()
        }
    }

    /**
     * gets External storage directory from the
     * current context
     * @return File
     */
    private fun getTokenFolder(): File {
        return File(this.context.getExternalFilesDir("")?.absolutePath + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)
    }

    /**
     * Gets authorisation flow so that the application can authenticate into Google Calendars
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT allows the app to use HTTP connections
     * @param clientSecrets secrets for authentication into Google
     * @return GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
     */
    private fun getAuthorisationFlow(HTTP_TRANSPORT: NetHttpTransport, clientSecrets: GoogleClientSecrets): GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow {
        return GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(FileDataStoreFactory(getTokenFolder()))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build()
    }
}
```

Here is my error message:

```
02/21 20:04:33: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 XL API 29.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.bluelightlite/com.example.bluelightlite.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 9795 on device 'Pixel_3_XL_API_29 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:48): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6831 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c133,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.bluelightlite
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/System.err: 2020-02-21 20:04:39.683:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
    2020-02-21 20:04:39.684:INFO::jetty-0.0
W/System.err: 2020-02-21 20:04:39.805:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:8888
I/System.out: Please open the following address in your browser:
      https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=475059597551-bugt3i0nnfe7unsoqt8ghu2ovm7dfrqg.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
W/System.err: 2020-02-21 20:04:39.823:INFO::Stopped SocketConnector@localhost:8888
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bluelightlite, PID: 9795
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bluelightlite/com.example.bluelightlite.MainActivity}: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Desktop;
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Desktop;
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:602)
        at com.example.bluelightlite.models.GoogleCalenderCredentials.<init>(GoogleCalanderCredentials.kt:15)
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCalendarsServiceModule.<init>(GoogleCalendarsServiceModule.kt:11)
        at com.example.bluelightlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Desktop;
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:129)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:81)
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.kt:52)
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.doInBackground(GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.kt:31)
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.doInBackground(GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.kt:22)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Desktop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.bluelightlite-6neG3BDx7D1LEKBl_6YMYg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.bluelightlite-6neG3BDx7D1LEKBl_6YMYg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.browse(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:129) 
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:113) 
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:81) 
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.kt:52) 
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.doInBackground(GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.kt:31) 
        at com.example.bluelightlite.modules.GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.doInBackground(GoogleCredentialsUtilityModule.kt:22) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9795 SIG: 9
```

I can't seem to find any alternative to `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp`. Any advice? Should I write my own Authentication code? Is there an Android version of AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp that I can use? I'm finding the documentation so vague and hard to read.

Developing on API 29 using a Google Pixel 3 XL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied [dnsiv's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850911/java-awt-desktop-class) answer and overridden `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` and I now have the following code:

```
private fun getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT: NetHttpTransport): Credential {

        val inputStream: InputStream = getCredentialsAsInputStream()
        val clientSecrets: GoogleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, InputStreamReader(inputStream))

        createTokenFolderIfMissing()

        val authorisationFlow: GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow = getAuthorisationFlow(HTTP_TRANSPORT, clientSecrets)

        val ab: AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp =
            object : AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(authorisationFlow, LocalServerReceiver()) {
                @Throws(IOException::class)
                override fun onAuthorization(authorizationUrl: AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl) {
                    val url = authorizationUrl.build()
                    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    context.startActivity(browserIntent)
                }
            }

        return ab.authorize("user").setAccessToken("user")
```

Comment: after  implement same at all i got error about oAuth not implemented @Marc Freeman

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have no idea if the API has changed in the year and 10 months since I ran into this problem and I no longer develop Android with Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - looks like you are running a loopback web server on port 8888, which is more of a desktop solution than a mobile one.

You are likely to get a more user friendly and reliable solution by logging in via a Chrome Custom Tab and using Google AppAuth libraries. It is not easy though.

Maybe have a look at my [Tutorial + Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) which may at least give you something to compare against.

Comment: So is there a particular Port that I should be using? 

I'll check the code samples now, thank you for leaving the link.

Comment: Usually a mobile app uses a private use URI scheme - not a loopback web server - I doubt you'll get loopback working reliably for a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through many learning curves including reading and implementing the idea from this posting. I finally figured this problem out and described my finding: [use google sign in to connect to google sheets api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512198/use-google-sign-in-to-connect-to-google-sheets-api/75575824#75575824)

The key is to follow the example from https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin to create a GoogleSignInAccount obj. Then, create a GoogleAccountCredential obj. to be used as the credential to Sheets.Builder.

Code skeleton

```
GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
Account account = signedInAccount.getAccount();
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                                context,
                                Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"));
credential.setSelectedAccount(account);

Sheets service =
    new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API")
            .build();
```

*NOTE*: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" is the SCOPE for the sheets API.

I hope that saves the reader time in the future. What I learned along this journey is that this authentication method changes. Pay attention to the date. Let me know when my finding is no longer valid.